# Strange error uploading screenshots to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, screenshot, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload new screenshots to my game's page on iTunes Connect, but when I do that, I get an error that doesn't have anything to do with reality and/or common sense. Basically, I upload a bunch of iPhone screenshots with correct resolutions, sizes, etc. and get an error saying that I didn't. I am beginning te feel like I am doing something wrong, even though I am pretty sure I am not.

The error goes like this: "Your binary indicates support for iPhone/iPod touch. You must provide an iPhone/iPod touch screenshot." Again, as you can see on the screenshot below, I have indeed uploaded those screenshots. The binary is correct and is targeted at iPhone/iPod Touch and iPad.

I have tried both Chrome and Safari, all to no avail. I have left a ticket to Apple's support, but that can sometimes take days, and I don't have that kind of time, as the approval process is lengthy enough without this.

([a screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9956376/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-22%20at%2001.11.56.png))

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a proxy for customer support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579). The fact that you're in too big a hurry to wait for the vendor doesn't make your question appropriate here.

Comment: If it's an app for the Phone/iPod touch, why are you uploading screenshots for the iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are uploading high res (Retina) screenshots. As of February 2012, the screenshots you upload for iPhone/iPad must be in high resolution (suitable for Retina devices). Apple says:

> The requirements for high-resolution images are 960 x 640, 960 x 600,
>   640 x 960, or 640 x 920 pixels. Images must be at least 72 dpi, in the
>   RGB color space, and the file must be .jpeg, .jpg, .tif, .tiff, or
>   .png.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's almost 1 year later, but for those still having this problem, just open the screenshot in preview and re-save it.

Worked for us!

Comment: Worked for me, too! This was the quickest and easiest way to get screenshots stripped of the alpha layer. Now if xCode would just actually output the correct format...

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly add the extension in finder first. Example 1.png/1.jpg instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem ..
Quotes from apple developer forms :

> Sorry to hear this is happening. This message means there are screenshot uploads that were started but never finished. Normally if an upload fails, App Store Connect will report an error and delete the unfinished screenshot for you. But it sounds like in this case a failed screenshot did not get deleted successfully.
>
> You can delete these yourself manually:  Go to your app version page
> where you see your screenshots.
>
> Click “View All Sizes in Media Manager”. This should take you to a
> page with all available display types and sizes.
>
> Click the “>” icon by each display size to expand every section.
>
> Unfinished screenshots show as a grey placeholder icon instead of an
> actual screenshot. Normally these tell you someone else on your team
> is in the process of uploading a screenshot. But if that’s not the
> case, then it means a screenshot upload failed, and did not get
> cleaned up automatically. If you see any of these:  Hover your mouse
> pointer over the screenshot. A red (-) icon will appear over the
> top-left corner.
>
> Click the (-) icon to delete the placeholder.
>
> If you have more than one localization for your app, use the locale
> picker in the top-right corner of this page to check each
> localization.
>
> Hope this helps!