# iTunes Connect Missing Screenshot Error

Tags: app-store-connect

I am trying to submit my app for review. I have included the screenshots for both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. I however do not have a screenshot for the iPad as my app only runs on the iPhone. When trying to save, I keep on getting error "You must upload at least one screenshot". The screenshots I had selected then disappear from the selection. I use Firefox browser. Is there any reason for such an error? Please help.

Comment: Are your screenshots the right size? Remember, for iOS 7 they must include the status bar area (i.e. they must be 20 pixels taller than they used to be).

Comment: I took the screenshots using Organizer  and iTunes Connect verifies if the image is the correct size. It accepted all my images but then gives the error.

Comment: As strange as it may sound, I used Firefox browser and then everything worked fine. Very strange...wasted hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: You should enter your own answer, and accept it. That is perfectly legal and is a good way to help others who may have the same problem later!

Comment: And this sort of thing suggests you're not alone in experiencing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147782/strange-error-uploading-screenshots-to-itunes-connect?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strange as it may sound, I used Firefox browser and then everything worked fine.

Comment: You should edit your original question and say the first browser (Safari, I guess). And then mark your answer as correct.